# Creating a tagging system for articles (Java MVC with Hibernate)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, publishing, tagging

I am trying to create a tagging system for my article publishing system that I created using a Java MVC framework with Hibernate. My thinking about creating a tagging system is as follows:

1. Create a ManyToMany relationship between `article_id` (in the articles database table) and `tag_id` (in the tags database table).
2. For this relationship to work, it requires an intermediary table called "articleId_tagId", which has two columns: article_id (Foreign Key in reference to article_id in articles) and tag_id (Foreign key in reference to tag_id in tags table). I have attached a screenshot of my this table below:

[image]

However, in my tags table, I see that the tag names could be duplicate for different articles (see the below screenshot). Should the tag names be unique in the `tags` table? If so, should I search through the `tags` table for duplicates before inserting a new tag?

[image]

Comment: Just show a list (multiple select box) of tags and allow the user to tag the article with those. Don't just allow new tags to be created by the article author. Tag creation should only be allowed for the administrator or some special users. That's how for instance stackoverflow operates.

Comment: thanks, that makes a lot of sense! I love SO's tagging system.